# Can multiple arborvitaes be made to grow uniformly to the same height?

Tags: trees, plant-health

Arborvitaes grown in rows often grow unevenly with some growing twice as much as others of the same age and with the same care. Is it possible to prevent this, and make all the trees in one row look alike?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where I live this issue is taken care of with a hedge trimmer.  If this is not what you had in mind you could try planting identical cultivars.  They are more likely to grow to a similar height and spread than a group of species cedars.  They will cost more, sometimes 5 times as much as wild grown cedars but your up front investment is rewarded by less trimming in future years.